# What's the name of these matrices?

Tags: matrices, terminology, permutation-matrices

I'm searching for the name of these sets of matrices:

2-dimensional:
$$\quad M_1^{2d}=\left(\begin{matrix}1 &0\\0 &1\end{matrix}\right), M_2^{2d}=\left(\begin{matrix}0 &1\\1 &0\end{matrix}\right)$$

3-dimensional:
$$\quad M_1^{3d}=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right), M_2^{3d}=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right),
M_3^{3d}=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$M_4^{3d}=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right),
M_5^{3d}=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right),
M_6^{3d}=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)
$$

It's something like the basis-set of orthogonal matrices, but without signs. I was searching for it, but I'm ending up at orthogonal or unitary matrices, and my matrices are something more specialized.

Comment: These are the $3 \times 3$ permutation matrices !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the [permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).  They are given this name because each such matrix [permutes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) the entries of a vector under multiplication.  For example,
$$
\pmatrix{&1\\1\\&&1} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{x_2\\x_1\\x_3}
$$
Such matrices are important, for example, in representing [graph isomorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) and in the definition of a [reducible matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html), which provides an important connection between matrix-analysis, [graph-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29), and the study of [Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Thanks for answer within 30sec :)

Comment: Glad to help! ${}$